# how to ObservableCollection add ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, visual-studio-2017

i making app unsplash with uwp windown 10. but limited response = 30. I don't get all. thank u so much

```
public static ObservableCollection<RootObject> listNewImage = new ObservableCollection<RootObject>();
PublicAuthorization publicAuthorization = new PublicAuthorization();

listNewImage = await publicAuthorization.Authorization();

while (listNewImage.Count > RequestParameters.perpage)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    RequestParameters.page += 30;
    RequestParameters.perpage += 30;
    listNewImage = await publicAuthorization.Authorization();
}

public async Task<ObservableCollection<RootObject>> Authorization()
{

    Uri auUri = new Uri(RequestParameters.publicAuUri);

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    string responseJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(auUri);

    ObservableCollection<RootObject> listNewImage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<RootObject>>(responseJson, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

    return listNewImage;
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more detailed information in your post.

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you ask but do you want to add the Authorization to listNewImage?

Comment: So sorry :D i want add objects ex listNewImage.add(listNewImage) but I do not old style. Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the API limits the number of results based on the `per_page` query parameter. If you increase this number, you will get more results. Then, if you want to get individual pages, you can just increment the `page` parameter to get next pages. Your code is currently adding 30 to the `page` and `per_page` parameters, instead you need to do just something like. `per_page` should stay the same and you are just requesting next pages.

```
RequestParameters.page++;
```

Comment: Hey bro. Thanks u so much :D